# Very mysterious deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I've read a large amount of information about deadlocks on the Internet, to be sure that I am not asking a stupid question. The following table, where the deadlocks happen, serves as an order queue. No records are actually deleted, only their status changes, i.e. PROCESSING, CANCELLED, COMPLETED.
I'm observing mysterious deadlocks on `SELECTs with UPDLOCK` on this table. The only peculiarity I see about the SELECTs is there is an inner `SELECT without UPDLOCK`, but that shouldn't matter. The table has row locking enabled. These SELECTS are run in parallel, by separate job schedulers. The meaning of such a SELECT is that it retrieves the first (earliest) order having one or more of the specified statuses (the abovementioned "PROCESSING, CANCELLED, COMPLETED"). The order with the minimum ID (the minimum ID is manually chosen, in the queries below it is 6850000) is considered as the "first" order. This is done for performance reasons. Here is an actual SELECT:

```
select * from TORDERSUMMARY with (updlock, rowlock) 
where ID in 
(select min(ID) from TORDERSUMMARY 
 where ID > 6850000  and (ORDERSTATUS in ( 'INITIATED' )) 
 and (ORDERDISPATCHSTATUS in ( 0  ,  2  ,  4 )) and (ORDERGROUPID is null))
```

There is a clustered index defined on the primary key, ID, in the table. As given by SQL Server Management Studio 2008, the estimated and actual execution plan of such queries is CLUSTERED INDEX SEEK. There are a number of non-clustered indexes on the table, and I hoped that a NC index operation deadlocks with a clustered index operation (I have read in detail about a number of such cases on the Net), but since only the clustered index is used in the best way (index seek), the cause doesn't seem to lie there.

The inner SELECT doesn't have UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK hints, so no multiple records are selected with locking. I cannot imagine any scenario where two such selects would deadlock. The UPDLOCK hint, of course, is because the code subsequently tries to update the status of the order (to mark it as processed, etc.).

Here is one deadlock XDL file from SQL Server Management Studio 2008 -- http://pastebin.com/ugCUbn80 . The server itself is 9.0.4035. The SQL queries are long, so for some reason they are truncated in the XDL file, but the SELECTs are certainly of the above type, because I have done manual stress tests of the server with such SELECTs and the deadlock seemingly randomly happens in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1: Don't build a clustered index on your artificial key; build the clustered index on your natural key and build a non-clustered index for your artifical key.

Comment: Technically that would be an opinion not a rule :).  There are some very good reasons to build your clustered index on a natural key, however they are some equally good reasons why you should build it on an artificial key.